# Can I run PyCharm as Admin on windows?

Tags: pycharm

I am trying to access STAF APIs on program running on PyCharm. Is there a way to run PyCharm as Admin?

```
ERROR:root:Error registering with STAF, RC: 21
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\ucce_auto\TestAutomation\common\python\pystafBase.py", line 33, in getStafHandle
handle = STAFHandle(name)
File "C:\STAF\bin\PySTAFv3.py", line 157, in __init__
raise STAFException(rc)
```

I get an Error with code 21 and one of the way to deal with this is to run PyCharm as Admin. However I couldnot find any material that will help me do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run a program with Administrator privileges on a windows machine, you need to right click the program file and select "Run as Administrator"

[image]